# axios first request succeeds second request fails

Tags: node.js, express, axios

i have a simple node node express server in which i get data from an api,it works fine on the first request but fails when i try to make a second request

```
const express=require("express");
const axios =require("axios");
const cors = require('cors');
const app=express();
app.use(cors());



app.get("/devices",(req,res)=>{

axios.get(
        'http://ipaddress/api/reports',
    ).then((response) => {
         res.status(200);
         res.json(response.data);
    }).catch((error) => {
        res.status(400)
        res.send("error")
    });

});
app.listen(3002,()=>{
    console.log("started on port 3002");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem i found here is you have initialize the server in your get route. The **app.listen..** code should be outside the get route implementation. I doubt if your code even runs for the first time. Change your code like:

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.get("/devices", (req,res) => {
axios.get(
        'http://ipaddress/api/reports',
    ).then((response) => {
         res.status(200).json(response.data);
    }).catch((error) => {
        res.status(400).send("error")
    });
});

app.listen(3002,() => {
    console.log("started on port 3002");
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: sorry i wrote it wrongly here but actually in my code its outside the get route

Comment: And you are getting the error on second attempt? What error you are getting??

Comment: when i enter the url localhost/devices on the browser the first request completes successfully and i get json data,now when i try again the browser just loads

Comment: Did you tried with postman? Also did you tried the api you are calling in postman if thats working fine?

Comment: The api works fine coz thats why the first request works also i tried the api via postman it works fine also...

Comment: Strange, coz i am trying the same code with an GET endpoint, and it's working fine with me..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198552/discussion-between-mohammed-amir-ansari-and-malouda).